# Creating a range from one column

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a column called "Marks" which contains values like 
 Marks = [100,200,150,157,....]

I need to assign Grades to those marks using the following key

```
<25=0, <75=1, <125=2, <250=3, <500=4, >500=5

If Marks < 25, then Grade = 0, if marks < 75 then grade = 1.
```

I can sort the results and find the first record that matches using Ruby's find function. Is it the best method ? Or is there a way by which I can prepare a range using the key by adding Lower Limit and Upper Limit columns to the table and by populating those ranges using the key? Marks can have decimals too Ex: 99.99

Comment: can you ask your question more elaborately ?

Comment: With ActiveRecord you can do stuff like `YourModel.where(mark: 0..25)`

Comment: What is mark? What is grade? Where do they come from? Table? some Model class? What are you trying to do?

Comment: Marks is computed by using a class Student. Grade and  Keys are stored in a table. I am looking for a proper way to find the grade of a student which is independent of sorting.

Comment: I am sorry but I didn't understand what you're trying to say. grade is a column in your Student class, i.e. students table, too?

Comment: Yes, Student has a grade which is stored against a student. Its value is computed using a table "Keys". I am trying to prepare the table "Keys" using the key string I mentioned in question.

Comment: This can be solved with a O(log n) algorithm, but with those sizes I'd just use a O(n) `index`/`detect` or whatever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without using Rails, you could do it like this:

```
marks = [100, 200, 150, 157, 692, 12]
marks_to_grade = { 25=>0, 75=>1, 125=>2, 250=>3, 500=>4, Float::INFINITY=>5 }

Hash[marks.map { |m| [m, marks_to_grade.find { |k,_| m <= k }.last] }]
  #=> {100=>2, 200=>3, 150=>3, 157=>3, 692=>5, 12=>0}
```

With Ruby 2.1, you could write this:

```
marks.map { |m| [m, marks_to_grade.find { |k,_| m <= k }.last] }.to_h
```

Here's what's happening:

[Enumerable#map](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-map) (a.k.a `collect`) converts each mark `m` to an array `[m, g]`, where `g` is the grade computed for that mark.  For example, when `map` passes the first element of `marks` into its block, we have:

```
m = 100
a = marks_to_grade.find { |k,_| m <= k }
  #=> marks_to_grade.find { |k,_| 100 <= k }
  #=> [125, 2]
a.last 
  #=> 2
```

so the mark `100` is mapped to `[100, 2]`. (I've replaced the block variable for the value of the key-value pair with the placeholder `_` to draw attention to the fact that the value is not being used in the calculation within the block. One could also use, say, `_v` as the placeholder.) The remaining marks are similarly mapped, resulting in:

```
b = marks.map { |m| [m, marks_to_grade.find { |k,_| m <= k }.last] }
  #=> [[100, 2], [200, 3], [150, 3], [157, 3], [692, 5], [12, 0]]
```

Lastly

```
Hash[b]
  #=> {100=>2, 200=>3, 150=>3, 157=>3, 692=>5, 12=>0}
```

or, for Ruby 2.1+

```
b.to_h
  #=> {100=>2, 200=>3, 150=>3, 157=>3, 692=>5, 12=>0}
```

Comment: Solves my problem but Is there any rails way of doing it shortly?

Comment: Someone else will have to answer that question, as the only Rails I'm familiar with have to do with transportation or carpentry.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_all/class):

```
Student.where(:mark => 0...25).update_all(grade: 0)
Student.where(:mark => 25...75).update_all(grade: 1)
Student.where(:mark => 75...125).update_all(grade: 2)
Student.where(:mark => 125...250).update_all(grade: 3)
Student.where(:mark => 250...500).update_all(grade: 4)
Student.where("mark > ?", 500).update_all(grade: 5)
```